# How to remove auto p tag in under img tag

Tags: html, wordpress

When I write a post by HTML content then p tag auto-generated under the img tag.

```
<img class="round-img" src="/single-post-1.jpg" alt="img">
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the automatic P tags by this filter. Place this in functions.php file

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

[Check this link for reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: note, that this will remove the automatic insertions for all p tags in your content.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

ADD this script in the page where you want to remove `<p></p>`

```
 <script>  
 $( document ).ready(function() { 
       $('img').closest('p:empty').remove();
});
 </script>
```

Comment: This code will remove all empty paragraphs, instead  $('img').closest('p:empty').remove();